# Cannot refresh-dependencies for Selenium with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, selenium, netbeans, gradle

I don't understand why Gradle isn't downloading Selenium, even with `refresh-dependencies`, given that **`Hibernate` downloads fine**.  Selenium is using the `mavenCentral` repo, just like `Hibernate`:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/sel$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/sel$ gradle clean run --refresh-dependencies
:clean
:compileJava
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.7.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/3.6.7.Final/hibernate-parent-3.6.7.Final.pom
Download https://jitpack.io/com/github/THUFIR/hello_api/master-SNAPSHOT/hello_api-master-1-gef696be-2.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.2.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.6.1/slf4j-parent-1.6.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.7.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.2.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/sel/src/main/java/net/bounceme/mordor/javascript/Main.java:25: error: no suitable constructor found for FirefoxDriver(URL)
        driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(url);
                 ^
    constructor FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to FirefoxProfile)
    constructor FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to Capabilities)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.867 secs
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/sel$
```

build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.javascript.Main'
//version = 'dev'
//group = 'com.some.project'
description = 'hello world KISS'


clean{
    delete "javascript"
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
if (!hasProperty(mainClassName)) {
    ext.mainClass = mainClassName
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.+'
    compile 'com.github.THUFIR:hello_api:master-SNAPSHOT'
}

jar.doFirst
{
    def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { it.name }
    manifestClasspath = manifestClasspath.unique().join(" ")
    println (manifestClasspath)
    manifest.attributes.put("Main-Class", mainClassName)
    manifest.attributes.put("Class-Path", manifestClasspath)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Your problem:

```
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/sel/src/main/java/net/bounceme/mordor/javascript/Main.java:25: error: no suitable constructor found for FirefoxDriver(URL)
        driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(url);
                 ^
    constructor FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to FirefoxProfile)
    constructor FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver(Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to Capabilities)
```

Here is argument mismatch problem.

### Root cause analysis:

From your `build.xml` file,

```
mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.javascript.Main'
```

which executes `Main.java` class.

In `Main.java` class, There is a declaration/object creation `driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(url);` which creates the error.

Here Java compiler cannot construct a `FirefoxDriver(URL)` object, because your call to the constructor does not match with it's any known constructor.

---

Specifically, the compiler found the constructor:

```
FirefoxDriver.FirefoxDriver()
```

but your call looks like below, which is mismatching:

```
new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(url); // remove url from this section.
```

---

### Solution:

Change your code in `Main.java` in line number `25`

```
driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver();
```

Hope, it will solve your issue.

Related Link:

1. [selenium-java : 2.53.0](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java/2.53.0)
2. [How to configure selenium tests with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389293/how-to-configure-selenium-tests-with-gradle)
3. [Executing Appium Tests with Gradle](http://testdroid.com/tech/appium-tip-20-executing-appium-tests-with-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Banging away at the keyboard like a monkey, got gradle to download the Selenium dependency.  How and why, don't know as of yet, I'll have to look for differences.

Kludge, which executes:

```
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
:clean
:compileJava
Download https://jitpack.io/com/github/THUFIR/hello_api/master-SNAPSHOT/hello_api-master-1-gef696be-2.pom
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar selenium-java-2.53.0.jar hello_api-master-SNAPSHOT.jar jna-4.1.0.jar antlr-2.7.6.jar jna-platform-4.1.0.jar commons-collections-3.1.jar netty-3.5.7.Final.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar gson-2.3.1.jar jta-1.1.jar slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar selenium-api-2.53.0.jar httpclient-4.5.1.jar selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.0.jar selenium-edge-driver-2.53.0.jar guava-19.0.jar selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.0.jar selenium-ie-driver-2.53.0.jar selenium-safari-driver-2.53.0.jar selenium-support-2.53.0.jar selenium-leg-rc-2.53.0.jar httpcore-4.4.3.jar selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar commons-codec-1.9.jar commons-io-2.4.jar commons-exec-1.3.jar
:startScripts
:distTar
:distZip
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.021 secs
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ cat build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.hello.client.HelloClient'
//version = 'dev'
//group = 'com.some.project'
description = 'hello world KISS'


clean{
    delete "hello_client"
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
if (!hasProperty(mainClassName)) {
    ext.mainClass = mainClassName
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.+'
    compile 'com.github.THUFIR:hello_api:master-SNAPSHOT'
}

jar.doFirst
{
    def manifestClasspath = configurations.runtime.collect { it.name }
    manifestClasspath = manifestClasspath.unique().join(" ")
    println (manifestClasspath)
    manifest.attributes.put("Main-Class", mainClassName)
    manifest.attributes.put("Class-Path", manifestClasspath)
}

thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ gradle run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
hello world 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.15 secs
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ 
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$ cat src/main/java/net/bounceme/mordor/hello/client/HelloClient.java 
package net.bounceme.mordor.hello.client;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import net.bounceme.mordor.hello.library.HelloLibrary;

public class HelloClient {

    private org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new HelloClient().runLibrary(args);
    }

    private void runLibrary(String... args) {
        HelloLibrary library = new HelloLibrary();
        out.println(library.hello(args));
    }

}
thufir@mordor:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$
```