# how to add the Gradle Kotlin dependency compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium'?

Tags: selenium, gradle, kotlin, dependencies, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What's the syntax to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17389293/262852) `Selenium` as a dependency using the `Gradle Kotlin DSL`?

error:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$ gradle clean

> Configure project :
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld/build.gradle.kts:18:18: Expecting an element
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld/build.gradle.kts:18:20: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld/build.gradle.kts:18:5: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.compile: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld/build.gradle.kts' line: 18

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 18:     compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
                            ^ Expecting an element

  Line 18:     compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
                              ^ Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

  Line 18:     compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
               ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                   public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.compile: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

3 errors

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloKotlinWorld$
```

build file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "2.0.4"
}

group = "xxx.yyy"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {

    baseName = "app"
    classifier = "inajar"
    version = "9"


    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Implementation-Title", "Gradle Jar File Example")
        //put("Implementation-Version" version)
        put("Main-Class", "HelloKotlinWorld.App")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this documentation : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html
For *Module dependencies*, the syntax is different between Groovy DSL and Kotlin DSL:

Groovy:

```
dependencies {
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '2.5'
}
```

Kotlin:

```
dependencies {
    runtime(group = "org.springframework", name = "spring-core", version = "2.5")
```

Note that you also need to replace  single quotes by double quotes ( see https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/#prepare_your_groovy_scripts)

In your case you should write

```
compile  (group= "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name = "selenium-java", version =  "3.+" )
```

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

runtime(group = <<<<< was failing for me

What worked for me:
runtimeOnly( group = "org.slf4j"...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).